# Excel 2010 user. What forumla should I use for my problem?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have 50 states to assign to three sales directors.

Using Excel I have tried, and failed to use nested IF formulas.

When a new sales lead is added, I want the appropriate sales director for the state to be assigned. For example, lead in NJ gets assigned to director X, lead in CO gets assigned to director Y.

I have the states broken down on the spreadsheet in their own columns.

Ex W3-W20 for Sales Director X, but I can't get the formula to work. I keep getting a #Value! error.

Here is what I have tried:

Attempt 1

```
=IF(B844=(W3:W20),"Rosado",IF(B844=(X3:X24),"Votaw","Snorty"))
```

Attempt 2

```
=IF(B844=W3:W20,"Rosado",IF(B844=X3:X24,"Votaw","Snorty"))
```

Attempt 3

```
=IF(B844="W3:W20","Rosado",IF(B844="X3:X24","Votaw","Snorty"))
```

Attempt 4

```
=IF(B844=(NJ,CT,NY,VT,DC,VA,MD,ME)"Rosado",IF(B844=CO,MT,CA,NV,AZ,OK,KS,UT,TX)"Votaw","Snorty"))
```

I've tried about 10 other versions of the above but can't get anything that works.

I expect that when a state is entered in one field (ex:J844) that the correct sales director assigned to that state auto-populates in another field(ex:L844)

Comment: Use `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX/MATCH` with the lookup table.

Comment: Thanks. I used Index/Match

Answer (score 1):

One way, In a separate sheet (ideally) you have a lookup table of states, say in column A, and the Director's Name associated with each state in Column B.

Personally I'd create a named range for this table and then the equation in L844, per your example, is a simple `VLOOKUP(J844, TheNamedRange, 2, FALSE)` where `TheNamedRange` could be defined as, for example, `Sheet2!A1:B50` or whatever your needs may be.

Comment: I would use index() with match() and have an alphabetic list of states in col A with the directors in col B... but same technique really. so plus one...

Comment: Index/match was a great suggestion. It was a quick solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, shown both methods here, index with match for the director and vlookup for the abbreviation:

[image]

I would have the table of data (cells A1 to C8 for me but larger for you) on a separate sheet (or even a separate workbook) - the functions will still get the results...

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a ton.